# SVG not rendering properly as a backbone view

Tags: javascript, html, svg, backbone.js, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to render a map of the world in svg (using https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json for the features). I am encapsulating the rendering logic in a Backbone View. When I render the view and attach it to the DOM, nothing displays in my browser, though the SVG markup is correctly generated when looking at the generated HTML. This renders fine when not encapsulating within a Backbone.View. Here's my code using Backbone.view:

```
/**
 * SVG Map view
 */
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'svg',
    translationOffset: [480, 500],
    zoomLevel: 1000,

    /**
     * Sets up the map projector and svg path generator
     */
    initialize: function() {
        this.projector = d3.geo.mercator();
        this.path = d3.geo.path().projection(this.projector);
        this.projector.translate(this.translationOffset);
        this.projector.scale(this.zoomLevel);
    },

    /**
     * Renders the map using the supplied features collection
     */
    render: function() {
        d3.select(this.el)
          .selectAll('path')
          .data(this.options.featureCollection.features)
          .enter().append('path')
          .attr('d', this.path);
    },

    /**
     * Updates the zoom level
     */
    zoom: function(level) {
        this.projector.scale(this.zoomLevel = level);
    },

    /**
     * Updates the translation offset
     */
    pan: function(x, y) {
        this.projector.translate([
            this.translationOffset[0] += x,
            this.translationOffset[1] += y
        ]);
    },

    /**
     * Refreshes the map
     */
    refresh: function() {
        d3.select(this.el)
          .selectAll('path')
          .attr('d', this.path);
    }
});

var map = new MapView({featureCollection: countryFeatureCollection});
map.$el.appendTo('body');
map.render();
```

Here's the code that works, without using Backbone.View

```
var projector = d3.geo.mercator(),
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(projector),
    countries = d3.select('body').append('svg'),
    zoomLevel = 1000;

coords = [480, 500];
projector.translate(coords);
projector.scale(zoomLevel);

countries.selectAll('path')
         .data(countryFeatureCollection.features)
         .enter().append('path')
         .attr('d', path);
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the generated SVG markup. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

[image]

Edit - Here's the overridden make method that ended up solving this, per request:

```
/**
 * Custom make method needed as backbone does not support creation of
 * namespaced HTML elements.
 */
make: function(tagName, attributes, content) {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagName);
    if (attributes) $(el).attr(attributes);
    if (content) $(el).html(content);
    return el;
}
```

Comment: What is the right way to do this now, given that the make method has been removed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue is that the "svg" element requires a namespace. D3 does this for your automatically; when you append an "svg" element, it uses the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg". For details, see [src/core/ns.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/ns.js). Backbone, unfortunately, does not appear to support namespaced elements. You'd want to change the [view.make](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1132) method. Then you'd need a namespaceURI property on your view to set the appropriate namespace, or just do it automatically for SVG elements for consistency with the HTML5 parser.

At any rate, a simple fix for your problem is to wrap your SVG in a DIV element, and then use D3 to create the SVG element.

Comment: Thanks! I overrode 'make' in my view and used createElementNS with 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' instead of createElement and that seems to do the trick. Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @rr: could you post your make method somewhere?

Comment: @PierreSpring: Done, not sure how relevant this is with newer versions of Backbone, I haven't been keeping up.

Comment: still relevant, just ran into it.  Thanks @mbostock, saved my face from being frozen in a very confused look :)

Comment: @Milimetric Make has been removed in Backbone 0.9.10.  See http://backbonejs.org/#changelog 0.9.10. More specifically the discussion at https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/2041  And the commits and pulls at https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/c1e62cda999dd902060ea04a11b81376aba63a16 and https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/8a42d536d8c862d259ca4d7909026798c046c3e9

Answer (score 4):

You could simply set the view's element in the initialize function as follows:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    // This is only for informaiton. The node will
    // be raplaced in the initialize function.
    tagName: 'svg',

    initialize: function () {
        this.setElement(
            d3.select($('<div/>')[0]).append('svg')[0]
        );
    }
);
```

This has the advantage of being explicite.

Comment: This is what's mentioned by the backbone authors here: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1357

Comment: You don't need to create a div though, `setElement(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg'))` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/nocircleno/QsEp2/
from http://nocircleno.com/blog/svg-with-backbone-js/

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  nameSpace: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  _ensureElement: function() {
     if (!this.el) {
        var attrs = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'attributes'));
        if (this.id) attrs.id = _.result(this, 'id');
        if (this.className) attrs['class'] = _.result(this, 'className');
        var $el = $(window.document.createElementNS(_.result(this, 'nameSpace'), _.result(this, 'tagName'))).attr(attrs);
        this.setElement($el, false);
     } else {
        this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'), false);
     }
 }
});
```