# Rendering in Backbone.js using d3.js and svgs

Tags: backbone.js, d3.js

In backbone.js, a view's render function generates unattached html which can be later attached to the dom.

Currently, I have to have an existing target in the HTML for me to append a svg to. I then use the data/enter pattern to insert elements into the svg. Is there a way to get d3.js to generate the svg without attaching it to the dom?

```
var svg = d3.select("#target").append('svg')
    .attr("viewBox","0 0 100 100"); 

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "black");
```

Alternatively, is it possible to provide d3 with a unattached dom element to append stuff to? Something like this? D3.js documentation suggests that select can accept nodes, but the following does not work for me either

```
var svg = d3.select(this.$el).append('svg')  // Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild' 
    .attr("viewBox","0 0 100 100");     

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([1,2,3])
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "black");
```

Comment: Have you tried `d3.selectAll([this.el])`? D3 might not be happy with a jQuery object, it might want a real array.

Comment: I have tried (does not work). By the way, the d3 documentation I was referring to suggests that d3 does play nicely with Jquery objects.  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select --> "These methods can also accept nodes, which is useful for integration with third-party libraries such as jQuery or developer tools"

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer in this post [SVG not rendering properly as a backbone view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9651167/783478)

```
d3.select(this.el)
```

does the trick!

Comment: Yes, d3 cannot select jquery objects. `d3.select(this.$el[0])` should also work.

Comment: Why can't d3 select jquery objects?